# How to only output commands from CRON?

Tags: cron

INPUT:

```
* * * * * ( /path/to/foo -x )
3 * * * * /full/path/tothing
3 3,2,4 * * * /full/path/tothing4 3
```

OUTPUT:

```
( /path/to/foo -x )
/full/path/tothing
/full/path/tothing4 3
```

**Q:** How can I truncate the line until the fifth space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
$ crontab -l|sed -r 's/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]){5}//'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cut`:

```
crontab -l | cut -d' ' -f6-
```

Comment: it's not deleting any zero, it's an range of field value , you can test using `echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 bla bla " | cut -d' ' -f6-0`

Comment: might be you have copied wrong, please type that command manually and see

Comment: both working in my system.., So I have updated that last one

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`cat /etc/crontab|awk '{ print substr($0, index($0, $7)) }'`

This will print each line without the 6<sup>th</sup> field.

Comment: Use `$6,` not `$7`...

Comment: it's a very bad idea, because the commands could have spaces, I updated the Q, ty!